# Displaying user specific data with ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to allow logged in users to save links. I want the links to display in an array when the user is logged in. Here is my code.

**JS**

```
app.controller('CommentCtrl', function($scope, $firebase, FIREBASE_URL, Auth) {
    var saveRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var savesync = $firebase(saveRef);
    $scope.saveLater = savesync.$asArray();
    $scope.saveIt = function(item, link, saver) {
        $scope.saveLater.$add({item: $scope.item.title, link: $scope.item.link, saver:   Auth.user.email});
    };
)};
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-disabled="!signedIn()" ng-click="saveIt(save)"</button>

<div ng-repeat="save in saveLater" ng-hide="!signedIn()">
    <a href="{{save.link}}" ng-show="Auth.user.email === save.saver">{{save.item}}
    </a>
</div>
```

I've tried a number of different ways. None have provided me with any luck. I've also considered using filters, but am certain there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: `<button ng-disabled="!signedIn()" ng-click="saveIt(save)"></button>` must be inside `ngRepeat` div.

Comment: hmm. They are on separate views. ng-repeat is part of a partial.

Answer (score 0):

Have a scope variable for if they are signed in or not that is checked and set when the controller is loaded.

```
$scope.signedin = signedIn();//When controller is loaded returns true or false
```

Then set the ng-disabled value on that variable.

```
<button ng-disabled="!signedin" ng-click="saveIt(save)"</button>
```

If you want to check if they are signed in for multiple scopes or something, just have an ng-init that will set the scope value for the "signedin" variable on the scope.

Also, the "save" is not available to you if it is outside the ng-repeat.  Angular is like, "which save? ...what?"  For every repeated item there is a "save" available, and you only want one of them.

If you really don't want the "saveIt" button inside the ng-repeat you will have to get that value(link) available on the scope, perhaps by having a scope variable of the link to save that is set when the link you want saved is selected.